# Unable to Use SharePoint PNP PowerShell in VSCode

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, visual-studio-code

Running this command in VScode doesn't work but it works in PowerShellPlus.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://something.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $userCredential
```

Error:

```
   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
   at SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

I've tried uninstalling VScode and removing any trace of SharePoint my machine but I'm not able to get past this error.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Following this blog post, I removed and reinstalled the SP PNP module.
https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=802

1. Delete all the SharePoint Components from the Control Panel
   (Add/Remove)
2. Open the GAC location
   (C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL), search for the term
   SharePoint and delete all the folders. (This is required since the
   reference is still old which is used by the PnP commands)
3. Re-Start the machine
4. Install the latest version of the SharePoint PnP

Comment: Why would you remove Sharepoint components from your machine when you are explicitly trying to use them? That would not solve your issue here. You have to be sure you've Imported any modules you plan to use in your VSCode profile. --- Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1  ---   PSPlus is using the default PowerShell profile and you must have Imports there for SharePoint for that to work in PSPlus. It needs to be in the same location as your PowerShell profiles as well.

Comment: @postanote  i removed and reinstalled the SP PNP module.  updating my post to provide more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I fixed my issue:
1. In VSCode open the Command Palette on Windows or Linux with Ctrl+Shift+P. On macOS, use Cmd+Shift+P.
2. Search for Session.
3. Click on PowerShell: Show Session Menu.
4. Choose one of the **___ (x86)** options

I was using x64 and that clearly didn't work.

Comment: Glad to hear this, you could Accept your own reply as answer so that it could also help others in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't uninatll the SharePoint trace in your machine and make sure you have install the corresponding PnP PowerShell library:

[SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/pnp-powershell/releases)

Then in VSCode, please install the PowerShell plugin:

[image]

Open the .ps1 which saved PnP PowerShell code and press F5 to run and debug:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm still seeing the same error.  The issue has to be with a setting/config in my VScode install.  I'm going to try removing VScode and all traces of the install, then try the steps you outline in your post.  Thx!

Comment: i didnt have any luck fixing the bug.  like i said in my first post, i'm able to use PowerShell Plus but not VScode.

Comment: Seems it's something related to your environment, as this works in my side. Now you can use PowerShell ISE instead if you want to test with PowerShell.

Comment: Do you know how to completely clear out VScode and all artifacts related to it?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/visual-studio-code/remove-vs-code-completely.html